# TypeError: dart.global.IrisRtcEngine is not a constructor

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The issue arose when porting a folder into my project, even with no references to the other module it ran into a white screen yet when building separately they work perfectly. My pubspec.yaml has been correctly configured, the google-services.json file is present, proguard was also enabled and updated my AndroidManifest.xml appropriately. I have also checked my build.gradle config on both app level and project level. Flutter doctor also ran with no errors.

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

environment:
sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.9
firebase_core: ^1.13.1
firebase_auth: ^3.3.9
random_string: ^2.3.1
in_app_purchase: ^3.0.0
flutter_braintree: ^2.3.1
http: ^0.13.4
flutter_webrtc: ^0.8.3
agora_rtc_engine: ^5.0.0
permission_handler: ^9.2.0
auto_size_text: 3.0.0
cached_network_image: 3.1.0+1
font_awesome_flutter: 8.11.0
google_fonts: 2.1.0
intl: 0.17.0
json_path: 0.2.1
page_transition: 2.0.4
shared_preferences: 2.0.11
timeago: 3.1.0
url_launcher: 6.0.15

On my latest build i got these errors, after the voip module was being migrated into my project

```
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56547/U6a7eRxcr7A=/ws
```

Running with sound null safety
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56547/U6a7eRxcr7A=/ws
TypeError: dart.global.IrisRtcEngine is not a constructor
at new agora_rtc_engine_web.AgoraRtcEngineWeb.new (http://localhost:56490/packages/agora_rtc_engine/agora_rtc_engine_web.dart.lib.js:179:26)
at Function.registerWith (http://localhost:56490/packages/agora_rtc_engine/agora_rtc_engine_web.dart.lib.js:63:28)
at Object.registerPlugins (http://localhost:56490/packages/voip_flutter_v2/generated_plugin_registrant.dart.lib.js:18:44)
at main (http://localhost:56490/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:32:35)
at main.next ()
at runBody (http://localhost:56490/dart_sdk.js:40590:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:56490/dart_sdk.js:40621:7)
at main$ (http://localhost:56490/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:31:18)
at http://localhost:56490/main_module.bootstrap.js:19:10
at Array.forEach ()
at window.$dartRunMain (http://localhost:56490/main_module.bootstrap.js:18:32)
at :1:8
at Object.runMain (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:8707:21)
at http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:23873:19
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3487:15)
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11518:12)
at Object._asyncStartSync (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3451:20)
at main__closure3.$call$body$main__closure (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:23885:16)
at main__closure3.call$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:23812:19)
at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3849:18)
at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12877:39)
at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12813:14)
at _ForwardingStreamSubscription._sendData$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12403:19)
at _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12349:15)
at _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12682:12)
at _MapStream._handleData$2 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12743:12)
at _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12708:20)
at tear_off. (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1392:45)
at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3849:18)
at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12877:39)
at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12813:14)
at _ControllerSubscription._sendData$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12403:19)
at _ControllerSubscription._add$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12349:15)
at _SyncStreamController._sendData$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12197:32)
at _SyncStreamController.add$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12078:15)
at tear_off. (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1450:48)
at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3849:18)
at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12877:39)
at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12813:14)
at _ControllerSubscription._sendData$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12403:19)
at _ControllerSubscription._add$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12349:15)
at _SyncStreamController._sendData$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12197:32)
at _SyncStreamController.add$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12078:15)
at _GuaranteeSink.add$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:23352:25)
at HtmlWebSocketChannel_closure1.call$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:23637:149)
at _EventStreamSubscription_closure.call$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:17865:26)
at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3855:16)
at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12877:39)
at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12813:14)
at _CustomZone_bindUnaryCallbackGuarded_closure.call$1 (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:13014:25)
at invokeClosure (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1281:26)
at WebSocket. (http://localhost:56490/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1300:18)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, i have been researching this issue but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounters this error i fixed mine with the pubspec.yaml, i downgraded the permission_handler dependency and it solved my issue.